# Anchor tags do not work

Tags: wordpress, scroll, hyperlink, anchor

I have anchor tags at the top of my page and link to a section below. The link does not move to that section though. The url at the top changes with the ID of the section but it just doesn't move.

It's on a wordpress site.

It doesn't link to a div with an ID it's to a `<section>` of the theme built by a page builder (I can only add custom classes not IDs). Is this the issue?

How do I get my anchor tags to work?

```
<ul class="inline">
    <li><a href="#section-56b33dac48448">Link Text Here</a></li>
    <li><a href="#section-56b33ceced2d2">Dermalogica Facials</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Glycolic Facial Peel</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Microdermabrasion</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: How does the corresponding anchor tag look like?

Answer (score 1):

```
  <a name="top"></a>
  There doesn’t need to be anything between the opening and closing tags.  
  Then, in the place you want to place the link, put 
  <a href="#top">link to top</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

That *could* be the issue, yes. If so, one possible solution is Navnit Mishra's. If you can create name attributes, that is.

If you can't do that either with the page builder you mention, you might have to write some JavaScript to put in the onclick attributes of the `<a>`s.

---

However, another issue might be that the targeted fragment identifier is already visible. (I.e. the top of the section that is the target of the `<a>` is present in the window already) If it is, the browser won't scroll it to the top if the window when it jumps to it, so you won't see anything change on the screen.